# Right-merging Horribly Made FEC Datasets

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I am having difficulty merging two datasets; both from the FEC. When I attempt to right-merge I get a many-to-many relationship and the merged dataset keeps duplicating numbers in all the wrong numbers.

**What I tried:**

```r
# 2014 US House Election Results
Election_2014 <- read_excel("2014 US House Election by State.xlsx", na = c("", "NA"))

# 2018 US House Election Results
Election_2018 <- read_excel("2018 US House Election by State.xlsx", na = c("", "NA"))

# 2014 and 2018 Election Results
Election_14.18 <- Election_2014 %>% right_join(Election_2018, by=c("STATE", "DISTRICT", "PARTY"))
```

---

**What I wanted to happen:**

```r
# Election_2014

`1` `STATE ABBREVIATION` STATE   DISTRICT `(I)` `TOTAL VOTES`   PARTY `GENERAL VOTES` `GENERAL %` 
1     2 AL                   Alabama 01       (I)   NA              R     103758        0.682                          
2     3 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              D     48278         0.317                          
3     4 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              W     198          0.00130                        
4     5 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    District Votes: NA    152234         NA                              
5     6 AL                   Alabama NA       NA    NA              NA    NA             NA                              
6     7 AL                   Alabama 02       (I)   NA              R     113103        0.673
```

to merge with:

```r
# Election_2018
`1` `STATE ABBREVIATION` STATE   DISTRICT `(I)` `TOTAL VOTES`   PARTY `GENERAL VOTES` `GENERAL %` 
1     3 AL                   Alabama 01       (I)   NA              R     153228        0.632                            
2     4 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              D     89226         0.368                            
3     5 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              D     NA             NA                                
4     6 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    Party Votes:    D     NA             NA                                
5     7 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              W     163         0.000672                         
6     8 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    District Votes: NA    242617            NA
```

**What I got:**

```r
`1.x` `STATE ABBREVIATION.x` STATE   DISTRICT `(I).x` `TOTAL VOTES.x` PARTY `GENERAL VOTES.x` `GENERAL %.x` 
1     2 AL                     Alabama 01       (I)     NA              R     103758                  0.682                                        NA
2     3 AL                     Alabama 01       NA      NA              D     48278                   0.317                                        NA
3     3 AL                     Alabama 01       NA      NA              D     48278                   0.317                                        NA
4     3 AL                     Alabama 01       NA      NA              D     48278                   0.317                                        NA
5     4 AL                     Alabama 01       NA      NA              W     198                     0.00130                                      NA
6     5 AL                     Alabama 01       NA      District Votes: NA    152234                 NA                                            NA
```

For 12,000 rows :/

---

I'm wanting just one 'D' and one 'R' per district -- if you can help me get rid of the District votes too, even better. I've only been using R for a month, so any words of advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may have completely misunderstood your question, but it looks like you want to do a `full_join()` then `reframe()` your dataframe to combine rows from each dataset by e.g. adding the GENERAL.VOTES together when PARTY, DISTRICT and STATE match.

Does this give you your expected outcome?

```r
library(dplyr)

Election_2014 <- read.table(text = "1 'STATE ABBREVIATION' STATE   DISTRICT '(I)' 'TOTAL VOTES'   PARTY 'GENERAL VOTES' 'GENERAL %'
2 AL                   Alabama 01       (I)   NA              R     103758        0.682                          
3 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              D     48278         0.317                          
4 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              W     198          0.00130                        
5 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    'District Votes:' NA    152234         NA                              
6 AL                   Alabama NA       NA    NA              NA    NA             NA                              
7 AL                   Alabama 02       (I)   NA              R     113103        0.673",
header = TRUE)

Election_2018 <- read.table(text = "'1' 'STATE ABBREVIATION' STATE   DISTRICT '(I)' 'TOTAL VOTES'   PARTY 'GENERAL VOTES' 'GENERAL %' 
3 AL                   Alabama 01       (I)   NA              R     153228        0.632                            
4 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              D     89226         0.368                            
5 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              D     NA             NA                                
6 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    'Party Votes:'    D     NA             NA                                
7 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    NA              W     163         0.000672                         
8 AL                   Alabama 01       NA    'District Votes:' NA    242617            NA ",
header = TRUE)

Election_2014 %>%
  full_join(Election_2018) %>%
  reframe(General_votes = sum(GENERAL.VOTES, na.rm = TRUE),
          `(I)` = unique(X.I.),
          .by = c("STATE", "DISTRICT", "PARTY"))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(X1, STATE.ABBREVIATION, STATE, DISTRICT, X.I.,
#> TOTAL.VOTES, PARTY, GENERAL.VOTES, GENERAL..)`
#>     STATE DISTRICT PARTY General_votes  (I)
#> 1 Alabama        1     R        256986  (I)
#> 2 Alabama        1     D        137504 <NA>
#> 3 Alabama        1     W           361 <NA>
#> 4 Alabama        1  <NA>        394851 <NA>
#> 5 Alabama       NA  <NA>             0 <NA>
#> 6 Alabama        2     R        113103  (I)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

NB. In future, please provide a sample of your data in a format that can be easily imported into R (using e.g. `dput(head(Election_2014))` and `dput(head(Election_2018))`) so we can test out potential solutions and don't need to try and recreate the data from your tables. This, and the lack of a clear expected outcome using your example data, are very likely why your question was downvoted. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more info.